# parallel_for slow inside visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++-2010

I use parallel_for from ppl.h and when I run the program from visual studio (2010) both debug and release version they run quite slow compared to running the executable from outside visual studio. Is there some option that I can disable, only in the release version maybe, to run the program faster inside visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running the program without the debugger being attached to it. In C++-Mode the shortcut for that is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

- If this is still slow, there may be some environment variable that is
  (not) being set when run from Visual Studio but when you run it
  outside of VS.
- If it's fast now, then the attached debugger probably slows your application down. If and how this can be improved 
  depends on your project type, i.e. programming language, I guess.